# Konvajs scroll to the center of layer

Tags: scale, layer, konvajs

I'm a little stuck on this problem. I would like to scale based on the center of the layer rather than a mouse pointer. 
Heres the Konva demo I got this from https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Zooming_Relative_To_Pointer.html
form

```
state.stage.on('wheel', (e) => {
      e.evt.preventDefault();
      var oldScale = state.layer.scaleX();

      var pointer = state.layer.getPointerPosition();

      var mousePointTo = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      };

      var newScale =
        e.evt.deltaY > 0 ? oldScale * scaleBy : oldScale / scaleBy;

      stage.scale({ x: newScale, y: newScale });

      var newPos = {
        x:  newScale,
        y:  newScale,
      };
      state.layer.position(newPos);
      state.layer.batchDraw();
    });
```

Also I want to have a way to have it go back to its original position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update that example by thinking that "mouse pointer" is at the center of the canvas. It can be something like this:

```js
var scaleBy = 1.01;
stage.on('wheel', (e) => {
  e.evt.preventDefault();
  var oldScale = stage.scaleX();

  var pointer = {
    x: stage.width() / 2,
    y: stage.height() / 2
  };

  var origin = {
    x: (pointer.x - stage.x()) / oldScale,
    y: (pointer.y - stage.y()) / oldScale,
  };

  var newScale =
      e.evt.deltaY > 0 ? oldScale * scaleBy : oldScale / scaleBy;

  stage.scale({ x: newScale, y: newScale });

  var newPos = {
    x: pointer.x - origin.x * newScale,
    y: pointer.y - origin.y * newScale,
  };
  stage.position(newPos);
  stage.batchDraw();
});
```

https://jsbin.com/jikuzutuse/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: this is good. How do I scale it back up to its original size though? For example, I've zoomed out/in a lot and would like the sage and all its elements to go back to its original size.

Comment: use `var newScale = 1`;

Comment: that did not do what I expect.    state.stage.scale(1, 1);
    state.stage.position(1, 1);
    state.stage.batchDraw(); it just went to the uper left hand corner but did not go back to how it looked before zooming can you send me a fiddle

Comment: Demo? Also, it should be `stage.scale({x: 1, y: 1})`;

Comment: that did it! Thanks @lavrton.